# How to send base64 png image to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, image, base64, fpdf

I have a base64 png image.
I'd like to use it in FPDF

**I create it like this:**

```
var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

**And send it to FPDF like this:**

```
$('#send').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var uri = "create_pdf.php?imgURI="+ dataURI;
    window.open ( uri, "Temp wind" );
});
```

inside the `create_pdf.php` I have:

```
require('fpdf.php');

$img = $_GET['imgURI'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image( $data, 0, 0, 200 );

$pdf->Output( "myimage.pdf", 'D' );
```

**Instead of the usual prompt to save PDF I get this error:**

> Image file has no extension and no type was specified: �PNG  IHDRSJ����IDATx......

How to properly send that base64 encoded image?

Comment: What's up with `str_replace(' ', '+', $img);`? Base 64 data shouldn't have spaces in it

Comment: Go back a step and try returning or saving the decoded PNG - make sure that data is valid before trying to process it into a PDF

Comment: @Brian I don't know, the PHP part might be totally wrong, and I'm not sure if I need to send that `dataURI` like `encodeURIComponent(dataURI)`

Comment: @Brian, yes, one idea was to store that image in some temporary folder and use it like any normal image url with FPDF, just I don't know how to do it... :\ any thooughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like pfdf takes saved iamge as parameter, not base64
Try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079040/2039657)

Comment: I have already seen that answer, it's I'm unable to understand how to use it in my case.

Comment: try saving the image localy, [here](http://j-query.blogspot.com/2011/02/save-base64-encoded-canvas-image-to-png.html) some simple tutorial

Answer (score 0):

FPDF image() function checks for the file type based on the $file string which should contain a filepath. If you offer a type eg 'png' in the optional parameters you can overcome this part.

Afterwards, FPDF will try to fopen $file within its _parsepng and _parsejpg functions so you can easily take use of the data wrapper
http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php

```
$fpdf->Image('data://image/png;base64,'.$image_data,null, null, 0, 0, 'png');
```