# PHP dataURL to png image

Tags: php, fpdf, data-uri, todataurl

I have captured an image from the canvas and sent it via a ajax post method to my php file.

Here I need to put it back into a png with a filetype and extension. As I will be adding this new image to a pdf using fpdf.

Here is my code. I am just left with a broken image link icon.

```
<?php 
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');
$imgEmbed = $_POST['embed'];

//convert base64 string into an image file by wrapping
//it in the png container

$parts = explode(',',$imgEmbed);
$data = $parts[1];
$data = base64_decode($data);

header('Content-Type:image/png');

$pdf =& new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();

//Set the source PDF file
$pdf->setSourceFile("test2.pdf");

//Import the first page of the file
$tppl = $pdf->importPage(1);

//Use this page as template
// use the imported page and place it at point 20,30 with a width of 170 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tppl, null, null, 215.9, 279.4, TRUE);

//Select Arial italic 8
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetXY(100, 100);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');
$pdf->Image($newIm,null,null,150,100);// x y h w 'png'

$pdf->Output("custom.pdf", "I"); // d send to browser, F send to local
// I auto open in browser window.
?>
```

Comment: `explode(',',$imgEmbed);` should be `explode('.',$imgEmbed);`? Does `Output` render as an image? I doubt. Change `header('Content-Type:image/png');` to `header('Content-Type: application/pdf');`

Comment: Output is a FPDF thing. it has no affect on making an image. I need fpdf to recognise the datauri as a png image hence the header. unfortunately your suggestion breaks the code even more... :(

Comment: Can you save the PNG to a temporary location on the server before writing it to the PDF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a JSON/base64 encoded image in FPDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078959/how-to-display-a-json-base64-encoded-image-in-fpdf)

Answer (score 1):

`$newIm='test.png';<br>
if(exif_imagetype($newIm)==IMAGETYPE_PNG) {<br>
    $file_type="PNG";<br>
}elseif (exif_imagetype($newIm) ==IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {<br>
    $file_type="JPG";<br>
}<br>
$pdf->Image($newIm,null,null,150,100,$file_type);<br>`

In Fpdf,The Image synatax reads the whole image pixel by pixel and if the image base is in png and we give the extension as test.jpg then it will give an error so here i have used exif_imagetype() which will give me the image type of the image.And then i will pass this $file_type in the syntax to get the result.And in my case it has worked.