# Image from database into PDF using FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have an image that is sent from an iPad app to an `SQL` database. I can retrieve this image and display in a web page using the following `php`:

```
$img = base64_encode($row['photoData']);
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, $img\"/>";
```

This displays fine. What I want to do now is put this image into a `PDF` document using `FPDF` however I am struggling to do this.

This:

```
$img = base64_encode($row['photoData']);
$pdf->Image($img);
```

give this error:

> FPDF error: Image file has no extension and no type was specified:

So I tried this (although I realise I will then have to look at how to get the size of the image sorted):

```
$pdf->Image($img, 20, 20, 20, 20 'JPG');
```

which give me:

> FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file:

What is the correct way to do this?

Or would it be easier to temporarily save the image to the server and then place the saved image into the `PDF`doc?

Comment: Well, the documentation of fpdf's `IMage()` function clearly states that it expects a _file_ (so a file name): http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm You could try to use a stream instead of a file as a workaround.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a JSON/base64 encoded image in FPDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078959/how-to-display-a-json-base64-encoded-image-in-fpdf)

Comment: Your closing statement **is** the correct answer. `Or would it be easier to temporarily save the image to the server and then place the saved image into the PDFdoc?` Not only easier but evidently the only way to get an image into the PDF using FPDF.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus is that so? And about the "easier": it makes things much more complex, especially because of the requirement for a storage location and a unique name and it slows processing down considerably.

Comment: Excellent - thanks to you both. Great advice.

Comment: I now need to work out how to get this echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, $img\"/>"; to be a save to file instead of displaying on screen.

Comment: There also appears to be an extension for `fpdf`: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script45.php  But still I would advise to take a look at `tcpdf`.

Comment: @arkascha I know you are right here. It is on the list of improvements but times pressing on this one and I need a quick fix.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Only to then invest more time to refactor things later? OK, it is your choice... but I doubt that will get fixed later :-)

Comment: @arkascha You might be right but I have the best of intentions.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, it is so. I will post an answer at some point so you can feel free to learn from it.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Oh, great, please reference me in that answer. That's gonna be fun!

Comment: @arkascha Not entirely sure the sarcasm is needed but I hope you enjoy my answer.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sorry, not sure why you understood that as sarcasm, that was not my intention. I simply love exchange over such topics, since it teaches us new skills. That's what I call fun... Maybe you want to take a look at my small answer below...

Comment: @RichardGriffiths You may want to reconsider if you really have to refactor your code to use physical files. My answer below clearly proves that what you ask certainly _is_ possible. But still I would advise to take a look at the `tcpdf` fork to overcome the limitations of the original `fpdf` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since FPDF cannot use base64 data to produce images on the PDF, I would recommend saving the file to the disk permanently as opposed to writing a temp file for every PDF operation.

This will save you a lot of I/O overhead.

---

Assuming your table has unique `photo_id` or `photo_name` to accompany `photoData` then you can use something like this to create your images and use them in FPDF.

I will also assume you have a `last_update` and `photo_extension` column.

```
<?php

$path = '/path/to/fpdf/images/';

$filename = $row['photo_id'].'.'.$row['photo_extension'];

$filepath = $path.$filename;

// If a physical file is not available then create it
// If the DB data is fresher than the file then make a new file
if(!is_file($filepath) || strtotime($row['last_update']) > filemtime($filepath))
{
    $result = file_put_contents($filepath, $row['photoData']);

    if($result === FALSE)
    {
        die(__FILE__.'<br>Error - Line #'.__LINE__.': Could not create '.$filepath);
    }
}

$pdf->Image($filepath);
```

If you plan on updating the `photoData` which is stored in your DB then you will have to make sure to also have a timestamp column and compare that timestamp against the `filemtime($filepath)` of the image on your disk.

Comment: Brilliant - all sorted. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Glad you like it :-)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments above this is possible by using a stream ("data url") to hand over the image data to the fpdf library *without* writing physical files to disk:

```
<?php
// load the 'fpdf' extension
require('fpdf.php');

// just for demonstration purpose, the OP gets the content from a database instead
$h_img = fopen('img.jpg', "rb");
$img = fread($h_img, filesize('img.jpg'));
fclose($h_img);

// prepare a base64 encoded "data url"
$pic = 'data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($img);
// extract dimensions from image
$info = getimagesize($pic);

// create a simple pdf document to prove this is very well possible: 
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello Image!');
$pdf->Image($pic, 10, 30, $info[0], $info[1], 'jpg');
$pdf->Output();
```

If this is a good advice is another question, this is merely meant to prove that this is possible...

Comment: Interesting proposal but I'm not quite sure I understand your example; why use `fopen()` at all? Could OP simply use `$pdf->Image('data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($row['photoData']), 10, 30, 40, 40, 'jpg');` and avoid the calls to `fopen()`, `fread()`, and `fclose()`? If so then this answer is better than mine because the only disk access would be the DB read operation for `photoData`. I am personally not familiar with this part `'data://text/plain;base64,'` so maybe that is the source of my confusion.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Of course the `fopen() fread() fclose()` sequence is _not_ required at all for the OP. That is why I added that remark to it clearly stating that fact. The code is meant as a primitive example to demonstrate the point here. Code examples should be complete in themselves if possible, so that they can be tried with as little implicit requirements as possible. Glad I could be of help and shed some light here. Have fun!

Comment: An interesting debate and another good answer. One issue however is the sizing of the image. In your example you have 40 x 40. I realise this could be altered but could it be dynamic ie to handle portrait vs landscape?

Comment: @RichardGriffiths That is a completely separate question about fpdf I'd say. In my eyes what you ask does make that much sense: pdf is a format to place elements in a very precise and distinct manner, quite unlike html. There is a workaroud however I remember using in tcpdf: it is easy in php to ask the dimensions of an image, you can use those values in the `->Image()` call. Again you don't really need a physical file for that, you can use the same url scheme as shown in this answer here. Oh, and for flexible and convenient layouting: https://github.com/arkascha/php-urithmetic  ;-)

Comment: I am not sure it is another question but that might be my ignorance. Your answer which is neat in that it does not have the overhead of saving the file to the server puts the image into the pdf doc with a size 40x40. This is not ideal and therefore all I was saying was that for this to be a complete answer to my original question it ought to display the image correctly. I accept that decoding the image to find its height and width may be a separate question but don't you think that it is key to this question too?

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Sorry, as I read it the question was about how to succeed in handing over the image. You indeed mention "I will then have to look at how to get the size of the image sorted", but you claim yourself that will be a step to be taken care of afte rthe issue at hand has been solved. This answer answers the question. Not more, not less. Also SO clearly asks to keep separate questions apart. Anyway: I added the simple call to query the image data and use it inside the call the the pdf libraries `Image()` method, just as suggested in my last comment.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths I do realize that the result of the code above is probably _not_ what you expected looking at the image dimensions. But that, again, is a different question: you did not even say what you expect, so what size the image should have in the final PDF. Since the image dimensions units are different to the units used inside the pdf library that simply is not defined. You have to define it to be answerable. For that I posted that link to the library I implemented ages ago to address exactly that question. I hope this helps, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Docs](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm) `FPDF::Image` accepts a filename as the first argument, not a binary blob.

If you want to use `FPDF` specifically, save the image to a temporary file first, and then pass that to `FPDF::Image`.

To do that, something like this should work:

```
$tmpFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'fpdfimg');
if (file_put_contents($tmpFile, $row['photoData'])) {
    $fpdf->Image($tmpFile);
    // save/display image
    unlink($tmpFile);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to just serve the image as a PDF (with no other content) you could use `Imagick`:

```
$im = new \Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($row['photoData']);
$im->setImageFormat('pdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $im;
```

Comment: Thanks. There are quite a few images and other text too so the temporary save to the server seems to be the best option at the moment. But I am struggling to see how you get from     echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, $img\"/>"; to be saving to the server instead of displaying on the screen.

Comment: I've added an example of saving using a temporary file

Answer (score -1):

Another solution for this ;)

Make a new php by copying and pasting this (piece of fpdf's code edited):

```
require('fpdf.php');
class DATAIMAGE extends FPDF
{
protected function _parsedata($file)
{
    // Extract info from a JPEG file
    $a = getimagesizefromstring($file);
    if(!$a)
        $this->Error('Missing or incorrect image file: '.$file);
    if($a[2]!=2)
        $this->Error('Not a JPEG file: '.$file);
    if(!isset($a['channels']) || $a['channels']==3)
        $colspace = 'DeviceRGB';
    elseif($a['channels']==4)
        $colspace = 'DeviceCMYK';
    else
        $colspace = 'DeviceGray';
    $bpc = isset($a['bits']) ? $a['bits'] : 8;
    return array('w'=>$a[0], 'h'=>$a[1], 'cs'=>$colspace, 'bpc'=>$bpc, 'f'=>'DCTDecode', 'data'=>$file);
}
}
```

Then call this php instead of fpdf.php in your main php.

You'll now be able to display an image simply by adding 'data' to the end of the function:

```
$pdf->Image($mysqlrow["blob"],0,0,40,0,'data');
```